# Remove one-character words that don't contain "a, i, and o"

Tags: bash

I'm creating a shell script that will convert stdin and output to stdout. Currently I have it converting everything to lowercase. I need to also remove single character words that are ***not*** "a", "i", or "o".

Here's what I've tried:

```
grep -o  '[a-z]\{2,\}' | while read WORD
```

- This successfully removes all single letter words.

Here's the desire,

- ./file.sh < myText.txt

Given that myText.txt has something like,
"Sample text t I o im"

Output:

```
sample text i o im
```

If awk, sed or other bash built-ins work better, I'd love to hear it.

Any help is appreciated, just trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution if one word per line is ok (like your going-in example did):

```
echo "Sample text t I o im" | \
  tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | \
  grep -o '\([a-z]\{2,\}\|i\|o\|a\)'
```

Comment: Awesome. Implemented into what I have, it works for 4 words per line.

Answer (score 0):

If `perl` is your option, how about:

```
perl -lane 'print join(" ", grep {tr /A-Z/a-z/; !/^[^aio]$/} @F)' myText.txt
```

Output:

```
sample text i o im
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only GNU `sed`, if that's allowed,

```
sed -E '
    s/.*/\L&/
    s/(^|\s)[bcdefghjklmnpqrstuvwxyz]($|\s)/ /g
' <<< 'Sample text t I o im'
```

prints

```
sample text i o im
```